# Программно не отображается кнопка Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Почему-то не отображается кнопка при программном написании кода, хотя тот же `TextView` исправно отображается. В чем может быть проблема?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("TextView");
        tv.setLayoutParams(params);
        layout.addView(tv);

        Button btn = new Button(this);
        btn.setText("Button");
        btn.setLayoutParams(params);

        layout.addView(btn);


        setContentView(layout, params);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Проблема в том, что первая добавленная вами `View` (`TextView`) занимает всё пространство контейнера и для кнопки не осталось места. Вы это задали через `LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT`.

Засим вам надо заменить `MATCH_PARENT` на `WRAP_CONTENT`

Comment: точно, спасибо!